# Null Value When Accessing String Array from appsettings.json in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I'm working on a .NET Core 6 project and I'm facing an issue where I always receive a `null` value when trying to access an array of strings from `appsettings.json`. Here is how I have set up everything:

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ColourCodes": [ "re", "bl", "gr" ]
}
```

Startup configuration: in `Startup.cs`, I have the following setup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _environment = environment;
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services. Configure<Colours>(_configuration.GetSection("ColourCodes"));
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
            {
                jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            });
}
```

I created a model named `Colours`:

```
public class Colours
{
    public List<string> ColourCodes { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I'm trying to access the configuration via `IOptions`:

```
private readonly IOptions<List<Colours>> _colours;

public ColorController(IOptions<List<Colours>> colours)
{
    _colours = colours;
}
```

However, when I try to access `_colours`, it always returns `null`. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong here. Could someone help me understand how to correctly retrieve the array of strings from `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
services.Configure<Colours>(_configuration);
```

Your `Colours` class represents setup in the config root, not in the nested `ColourCodes` section. `_configuration.GetSection("ColourCodes")` will result in `[ "re", "bl", "gr" ]` part "fetched" which can't be bound to the `Colours` type correctly.

If you don't want the value to be stored in the root of the config - nest in another JSON object:

```
{
  "Colours": {
    "ColourCodes": [
      "re",
      "bl",
      "gr"
    ]
  }
}
```

And adjust code to:

```
services.Configure<Colours>(_configuration.GetSection("Colours"));
```